# Gtk3 Comboboxtext widget default item

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

In Gtk3 development am using gtkcomboboxtext widget in glade i selected active item as zero but its not working..So i wrote this line
`gtk_combo_box_set_active (combo,0);` 
in my code.This works but its throwing some warning while compiling how can i do this in a clean way?

The warning shown is this

```
usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkcombobox.h:99:15: note: expected ‘struct GtkComboBox *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkComboBoxText *’
test.c:247:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_combo_box_set_active’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkappchooserbutton.h:29:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:45,
                 from test.c:1:
```

Comment: More code...... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from the docs `gtk_combo_box_new` (it's the same for GtkBuilder created widgets, they are all cast to GtkWidget, but read on):

```
gtk_combo_box_new ()

GtkWidget *         gtk_combo_box_new                   (void);
Creates a new empty GtkComboBox.

Returns :

A new GtkComboBox.
Since 2.4
```

and another `gtk_combo_box_set_active`

```
gtk_combo_box_set_active ()

void                gtk_combo_box_set_active            (GtkComboBox *combo_box,
                                                         gint index_);
Sets the active item of combo_box to be the item at index.

combo_box :

A GtkComboBox
index_ :

An index in the model passed during construction, or -1 to have no active item
Since 2.4
```

The issue is obviously that the returnvalue of `gtk_combo_box_new` is a `GtkComboBox` already cast to `GtkWidget` (convenience) whereas `gtk_combo_box_set_active` expects a `GtkCombobox`.

To silence and fix the warning use either the cast macro `GTK_COMBO_BOX (combo)` or `(GtkComboBox*)combo` instead of bare `combo`.

Next time have a look at tha API docs first (web or via devhelp).